# How to Convert a negative milliseconds into correct timeZone in Java

Tags: java, date, time, timezone

I am working with Java dates , I am unable to get out of this issue.
In my file the Time value is saved like (HH:MM:SS)

00:00:08
below is the code and output ..

```
  String timeinsec = "00:00:08";
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
  Date time =  df.parse(timeinsec);
```

What happened is when I assigned the value and time variables. time.fastTime variable show
"-17992000"

when I convert back this value to HH:MM:SS it shows me.
"-4:-59:-51"

Anybody can help to fix TimeZone issue.
My current time zone is GMT+5

Comment: can you show the convert back pattern

Comment: You are trying to parse time of day as a full date. That can't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this;

```
int day = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds);
long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) - (day * 24);
long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) * 60);
long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) * 60);
```

Answer (score 2):

here is the convert back code:

```
Date new_time = Time_array.get(0).time;  //-17992000 stored in "fastTime" variable
long diff = ((long)new_time.getTime());  //TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS

long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
String hms = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", diffHours, diffMinutes, diffSeconds);
```

in dubug: the value of hms = -4:-59:-51

Answer (score 2):

I was trying various ways so finally i wrote this code and my requirement is fulfilled.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String timeinsec = "00:00:08";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date time =  df.parse(timeinsec);
cal.setTime(time); 
hms = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", cal.get(Calendar.HOUR), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

The output was : 00:00:08

Answer (score 0):

hh is 1~12. You should use HH (0~23)

```
String timeinsec = "00:00:08";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date time =  df.parse(timeinsec);
```